# Perl strings into variable calculation

Tags: string, perl, variables, logfiles

In my code I am searching for some information in bunch of log files that generate every 15 min (the time part is not so important though) and it's giving me certain output as shown below. But that's not what I want.

My end goal is to calculate the output which means I am trying to turn this string of numbers into variables and calculate the total for each restaurant, and then I want to total for all the restaurants.

Honestly I need to track these numbers and calculate the what result I need. I'm so confused with what I have so far so I need help!

I hope I made my concern clear.

Sample log file:

```
Total number = 0 for Mcdonalds .....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 5 for Mcdonalds .....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 12 for Burger King.....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 2  for Culvers .....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 2  for Mcdonalds.....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 19  for culvers.....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 0 for Mcdonalds .....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 0 for Mcdonalds .....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 0 for Mcdonalds .....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 19  for culvers.....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 0  for culvers.....somelog.java:(000)
```

#### Current output

```
Total number = 5 for Mcdonalds .....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 12 for Burger King.....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 2  for Culvers .....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 2  for Mcdonalds.....somelog.java:(000)
Total number = 19  for culvers.....somelog.java:(000)
```

#### What I need:

```
Total Number for Mcdonalds = 7
Total Number for Culvers   = 21
Total Number for BK        = 12
Total for all              = 40
```

#### Perl Code

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use File::Find::Rule;
use Date::Parse;

my ($dir,   $type,  $fh,    $line,  $str_1,
    $str_2 );

$dir = '/dir/test/';
$type = '*';
$str_1           = 'Total Number= 0';

$str_2           = '(java:000)';


my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()->name($type)->in($dir);

open $out, '>>', "output_log" or die "Unable to open 'output_log' : $!";
print $out "\Logs \n";
print $out "--------------------------\n";
close $out or die "Unable to finish writing output_log : $!";

for my $file (@files) {

    open $fh,  '<',  $file        or die "can't open $file: $!";
    open $out, '>>', "output_log" or die "Unable to open 'output_log' : $!";

    while ( $line = <$fh> ) {
# Here I am searching for those which are not equal to zero 
#and which has the tail java:(000)

        if ( $line !~ /$str_1/ && $line =~ /$str_2/ ) {
            print $out $line; #So here my output lines are all which are not zero.
        }
    }

    close $out or die "Unable to finish writing output_log : $!";
}
```

Comment: You've made your code much harder to read by delcaring all your variables in one long list at the top of your program. Variables should be declared as *late* as possible, probably where they are first used.

Comment: The variable `$type` isn't defined when you call `File::Find::Rule`. You must have got a warning message?

Comment: That code doesn't produce the output you say it does. Your program prints only lines that contain `java:000`, and none of your output contains that string. Can you show your real code and output please? It would help a lot if you gave a sample of the log file you're processing too.

Comment: Do you really have both `Culvers` and `culvers` in the input? And is it really `Mcdonalds` instead of `McDonald's`?

Comment: Well, i did few edits to the post please refer them..names do not matter...The only thing i am stuck is finding how to parse the numbers and calculate the result i need...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am assuming that you are getting the output as shown. So I am just focusing on the part to unify them

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
my $string = "Total number = 5 for Mcdonalds
    Total number = 12 for Burger King
    Total number = 2  for Culvers
    Total number = 2  for Mcdonalds
    Total number = 19  for culvers";
my @rows = split("\n",$string);
my %hash = ();
foreach my $row (@rows) {
    if($row =~ /(\d+)\s+for\s+(.*)$/i) {
        my $comp = lc($2);
        if(exists($hash{$comp})) {
            $hash{$comp} = int($hash{$comp}) + int($1);
        } else {
            $hash{$comp} = int($1);
        }
    }
}
foreach (keys(%hash)) {
    print $_ . "...." . $hash{$_} . "\n";
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `int`?

Comment: This works well!! but quite not sure how to calculate these results from the hash key values @user3778815

Comment: There is no point in the non-greedy `.*?` when it is anchored at the end with `$`

Comment: yeah sorry silly mistakes no need for .*? int is used cause regex returns strings not int.

Comment: u can use the key of the hash as company name and value as the value. and modify accordingly @Sang.P